# How does one pronounce I'd've?

Tags: pronunciation, contractions

I think it's the first time I've ever seen a double contraction like this:

> "That’s, let’s be optimistic, a 30 to 50 mile radius at least in which we are the only two people left. I can’t even calculate how many people that means just vanished.” If I wasn’t driving, **I’d’ve** squeezed my eyes shut and shrunk down in the seat, to try to combat the thoughts this line of talk was forcing into my mind. <sup>[source](https://www.fimfiction.net/story/273206/4/the-coming-storm/one-step-forward)</sup>

Is this correct standard English?

How does one pronounce that thing?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly normal in spoken English.  I'm not sure how to write the pronunciation, but it's something like *eye-dv*.  [Here is a synthesized voice saying it; it's not perfect but it's reasonably close.](https://www.naturalreaders.com/online?s=V27sadhxcqwo0088w4ww8wcg8c8.pdf&t=NaturalReader%20Document)

Comment: Pronounce like: *aye-dove*, as in *aye-aye captain!* and *dove* the bird. But then, nearly don't pronounce the *o* in *d**o**ve*, and emphasize/elongate the *v* just a touch.

Comment: Made a quick video for you.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWEeaxC6qrU

Comment: As for whether it’s “standard” English, there’s a [question about _I’d’ve_ on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/689/is-idve-proper-use-of-the-english-language); and [_you’d’ve_ has been mentioned on ELL before](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41407/meaning-of-youd-of-thought).

Comment: It's fine in informal English, although even there its written form is a lot less common than its spoken form. (I've only seen it a few times, but I've heard it a lot more.)

Comment: It's pronounced almost exactly like "I'd *of*", to the point that some native speakers conceptualize and spell it that way.

Answer (score 1):

This is a contraction of "I would have". It's normal in writing to contract "I would" to "I'd", and "would have" to "would've" but it's unusual to contract them all three together. It's not necessarily incorrect, just unusual. Normally you'd see

> I'd have

or

> I would've

I agree with the comment that describes the pronunciation as being identical to

> I'd of